# Programaticly change Active Directory password with SetPassword, create multiple password

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

I am changing my exchange password with the UserPrincipal class' SetPassword method. But the problem is that it look to create an other password and keep the old one. Ex : My current password is "123", if I do this :

```
PrincipalContext Adcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", "superuser", "password");
UserPrincipal userdomain = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Adcontext, "UserIWantToChange");

userdomain.SetPassword("newpassordcompletlynewinsaneinthebrain");
```

And I try to login to outlook, the 2 password will work ! If I use "ValidateCredentials", the 2 will work too. Is this normal ? How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found why. I am answering my onw question to help further people who have the same problem. It is due to the **Cached Domain Credential**. You can disable it. Here's an helpful link that's explaining how to do it. [Disable Cached Domain Credential](https://serverfault.com/questions/375036/how-can-i-clear-cached-domain-credentials)